# How to use html-webpack-plugin with existing express templates?

Tags: html-webpack-plugin, express-generator

I've intalled the express-generetor npm module and like how the project is structured with the jade files used as templates. However I also like to use the HTML-webpack-plugin which generates its own files, what is the best way to go about integrating both approaches?

Answer (score 0):

- Step1:

Generate your html file(s):

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'page1': './apps/page1/scripts/main.js',
    'page2': './apps/page2/src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "apps/[name]/build/bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['page1'],
      filename: 'apps/page1/build/index.html'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['page2'],
      filename: 'apps/page2/build/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

- Step2: Add the generated html file(s) to your jade file

  include ../../public/index.html